# BufferedReader doesn't receive string from LXSocket

Tags: java, objective-c, client, exc-bad-access

i'm developing a simple test to connect via socket a java server application with an objective-c client side.

This is the java side:

```
BufferedReader dis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); 
String message = dis.readLine();
System.out.println("Message Received: " + message);
dis.close();
socket.close();
```

This is the objective-c side:

```
- (IBAction)click:(id)sender{
    @try {   
        [socket sendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[toSend text]]];
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to send data");
    }
    [toSend resignFirstResponder];
}
```

There are many problems:

in this way the output of server is:

```
Message Received: null
```

i read on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975410/serversocket-java-not-reading-inputstream) that `readLine()` needs to receive a string with `"\n"` that ends string, so i edit the line upon adding `\n`:

```
[socket sendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n",[toSend text]]];
```

but i retrieve an error on this line: EXC_BAD_ACCESS like in screenshot

[image: EXC_BAD_ACCESS]

What could be the problem? can someone help me?

Comment: Are you saying the code runs without exception without the newline, but generates EXC_BAD_ACCESS with it in? (Can you reconfirm this?)

Comment: confirm! :) what could be the error?

Answer (score 1):

I made a prototype in the Java side, and I don't have Objective-C/iOS or an Apple product.
I suspect the problem could be either in iOS or the Java side. So I hope you're sending text from iOS correctly.

Proposed code:

```
BufferedReader dis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), Charset.defaultCharset()));
```

The class InputStreamReader need a defined character set. The charset is supposed to be required, not optional! according to Sun documentation.

For expediency, pls just include more code for clean compile next time. Thanks.

Good luck n try it out!

Tommy Kwee

Answer (score 0):

According to your modified post/question, you got an exception from the Objective-C side. So possibly the problem is not on the Java side.
For debugging purposes, I am proposing to make the C code simpler, like...

```
BOOL success;
success = [socket SendString: @"Hello World!"];
if (success != YES) {
  NSLog(@"Fail to send")
}
```

Notes:

- I am not familiar with Objective-C, and I could not find documentation from Apple on it. If you know, please tell me/us.
- I did not use code "[toSend text]" because I did not find any references on it.
- Other iOS developers are saying "%@" is meant for objects. Is code [toSend text] an object?

Finally, making a socket connection and achieving communication should be possible and not so hard, and eventually we'll get there. So let's do it!